# How can i configure VS Code's comment shortcut to insert erb or css line comment syntax within css.erb files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can i configure VS Code to insert the correct line comment characters when in a css.erb file? Ideally I'd like it to do the following:

- if line is embedded ruby, i.e. wrapped in `<%` `%>`, then insert `#` after the `<%`
- else just comment as if it were a line of css markup, i.e `/*` `*/`

Comment: It would be helpful to see some sample text for those of us not familiar with css.erb files.